Should we add validation to through model in Rails?
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborators
  has_many :users, :through => :collaborators
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collaborators
  has_many :products, :through => :collaborators
end

class Collaborator < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :user
  validates :product_id, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
 end

I'm having problems with the validate part in through model. When I create a new record from the User model
User.create!(name: "user name", product_ids: [1, 2, 3])
=> It returns the error Collaborator is in valid.
The problem here is that validates :user_id, presence: true blocks this. And if I comment this line again, it works normally again and new records created in the Collaborator table still have user_id and product_id
I'm using rails 6.1
Should we add validation to through model in Rails?

Please add your rails version to the question.  If it is Rails 5 or greater the validation is redundant because of the belongs_to. That being said you need to create Collaborators and a simple User.create does not do that.

PSA: It's 2024 and the Ruby 1.8 => notation is long obsolete for cases like this. You can write through: :collaborators which matches up with notations used in JavaScript and Python, etc.

@dbugger Yes, I'm using rails 6.1. Can you provide me with a link or document that says that from Rails 5, adding validation is not necessary?

@Kevin its right in the Release notes: "belongs_to will now trigger a validation error by default if the association is not present. You can turn this off on a per-association basis with optional: true."

You should validate this, and you should have a not-null constraint on the columns. You certainly don't want to create a bunch of collaborator records with no user_id.

@user229044 and add a uniqueness validation and unique index if you don't want duplicates per user/product combo.

In rails >= 5 belongs_to notation automatically adds validation. See 6.1 source
If validation doesn't work in your case, probably you use Rails.application.config.active_record.belongs_to_required_by_default
Try to grep it
git grep belongs_to -- config

I think it's better to use default config. And if you really don't need to validate presence of user — just add optional: true option
belongs_to :user, optional: true

It depends on your business logics, and it's unlikely somebody in the Internet knows about it:)
Anyway it is recommended to add NOT NULL constraint to database layer if you validate presence of some column in application layer
BTW starting from Rails 5 intermediary abstract model ApplicationRecord is used
